# scope of variables within/outside a block

Tags: ios5, objective-c-blocks

I am wondering what is the scope of variables when using the same name of a variable within and outside a block. An example will talk from itself:

```
NSSet *test = [NSSet setWithObjects@"Test"];

void (^onComplete)(id) = ^(NSSet *test) {

    // do we see the variable define as an argument of the block or the variable define outside of the block?
    NSSet *test2 = test;

}

NSSet *test3 = test;
```

Is there any possible conficts here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables hide outer scopes. So in the block, `test` is the parameter, not the outside variable.